# Add-on to Google Forms - constant variables - Save values permanently

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm creating a Google Form add-on. The user indicates in the sidebar which file to use and where the files are to land in Google Drive. The add-on needs to save these two variables permanently on the server.  How can I save the user settings?

My HTML - sidebar on right, when a owner of this form is creating questions and type of answers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
      <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      Link to your document:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="document"><br><br>
      Link to your folder in your Google Drive:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="drive"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Prześlij">
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <script>
        function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {        
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).processForm(formObject);  
      }

      function close() {
        google.script.host.close();
      }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
My code.gs 

function onOpen() {
  FormApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Additional menu')
  .addItem('Answers to file', 'showSidebar')
  .addSeparator()
  .addToUi();
}


function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('Save your form!')
      .setWidth(300);  
  FormApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(html);
}



function processForm(formObject) {
var ui = FormApp.getUi(); 

var linkToDoc = formObject.document; 
ui.alert ('Link do dokumentu to: '+linkToDoc);
var idOfDoc = linkToDoc.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
ui.alert ('ID dokumentu: '+ idOfDoc);

var linkToDrive = formObject.drive; 
ui.alert ('Link do folderu na Dysku Google: '+linkToDoc);
var idOfDrive = linkToDrive.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
ui.alert ('ID folderu na Dysku Google: '+ idOfDrive);  

}



function myFunction(e) { //Trigger that starts when the end user completes and sends the form.

How can I use here variables from proccessForm()? I mean idOfDoc and idOfDrive.  

}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are having? Where do you want to store the user input?

Comment: Properties Service can be used for persistent storage, and is typically used to store user settings.  Data in Properties Service is stored as a key/value pair, and the value can only be a string.  Data can not be stored as an object, but you can stringify an object first before storing it.  Properties Service has limits to the key length, value length and overall data amount.  The documentation can be accessed through the code editor from the "Help" menu.

Comment: @AlanWells yes this is it. I used it and works great. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now works great. Below is my function to save my variables from form.  I've added one additional input in form, so that's why here it's mail variable.

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function processForm(formObject) {
var ui = FormApp.getUi(); 
var linkToDoc = formObject.document; 
ui.alert ('Link to doc: '+linkToDoc);
var idOfDoc = linkToDoc.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
ui.alert ('ID of doc: '+ idOfDoc);
var linkToDrive = formObject.drive; 
ui.alert ('Link to drive: '+linkToDoc);
var idOfDrive = linkToDrive.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
ui.alert ('ID of folder in Google Drive: '+ idOfDrive);
var mail = formObject.mail;
ui.alert('Your email: '+mail);
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(idOfDoc);
var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(idOfDrive);  
var myJSON3 = JSON.stringify(mail);
var myJSON4 = JSON.stringify(linkToDoc);
var myJSON5 = JSON.stringify(linkToDrive); 
scriptProperties.setProperty('doc', myJSON);
scriptProperties.setProperty('drive', myJSON2);
scriptProperties.setProperty('mail', myJSON3);
scriptProperties.setProperty('linkdoc', myJSON4);
scriptProperties.setProperty('linkdrive', myJSON5);
}
```